# Why is my LightDM startup script failing despite "|| true"?

Tags: bash

**Context:**

I want to add a conditional startup script to LightDM that detects screen resolution and if it is too high, it scales the screen via xrandr.

Script (irrelevant to this question):

```
#!/bin/bash

# If the display has higher resolution than X_THR x Y_THR,
# it will be scaled by a factor of SCALE x SCALE.
X_THR=3840
Y_THR=2160
SCALE=0.5

# First, check if exactly one display is connected.
# Otherwise, we don't really know what's happening and
# the script should terminate without making changes.
if [ "$(xrandr | grep -w connected | wc -l)" -ne 1 ];
then
  echo "Not adjusting screen settings automatically,\
        detected $(xrandr | grep -w connected | wc -l)\
        screens";
  exit 0;
fi

# Note that the screen may either be marked as "primary"
# or not. By treating "primary" as a field separator in AWK
# we handle both cases.
read display_name resolution <<<\
  "$(xrandr | grep -w connected | awk -F'\\sprimary\\s|[ \\+]' '{print $1,$3}')"

read x_dim y_dim <<<\
  "$(echo $resolution | awk -F'x' '{print $1,$2}')"

if [ "$x_dim" -ge "$X_THR" -a "$y_dim" -ge "$Y_THR" ];
then
  echo "Updating X server scale."
  xrandr --output $display_name --scale "$SCALE"x"$SCALE"
fi
```

LightDM configuration file (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-labdoo.conf):

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=LXDE
display-setup-script=/opt/labdoo/setup/startup_scripts/screen_scaling.sh || true
```

**What happened:**

By a mistake, I changed the preamble in the script from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`, which resulted in the script failing with some syntax error.

**Expected behaviour:**
I would expect LightDM to ignore the failure of the script thanks to the `|| true` in `display-setup-script`.

**Actual behaviour:**
LightDM failed to load the greeting screen. In /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log I saw a line:
`Exit status of /opt/labdoo/setup/startup_scripts/screen_scaling.sh || true: 1`

How can the exit status be 1?

Comment: Likely the value of `display-setup-script` inside config does not evaluate as shell expression (does not understand `|| true` at all and just takes name of executable to run) ? In such case you'd need to handle errors inside the script (or wrap script in another script).

Comment: What blami says. `|| true` is a shell construct. It only matters if your string is run through `system()`, not if it's directly executed. The bash tag isn't relevant here because the problem here is that _neither bash or any other shell_ is being invoked at all.

Comment: Now, if you had used `display-setup-script=/bin/sh -c '/opt/labdoo/setup/startup_scripts/screen_scaling.sh || true'`, **that** would have treated `|| true` as syntax.

Comment: BTW, `<<<` is the most obvious syntax you're using that `sh` isn't guaranteed to support. And `test -a` [is marked obsolescent](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/test.html) (look for the `[OB]` markers in the standard document); use either the POSIX syntax `if [ "$x_dim" -lt "$X_THR" ] && [ "$y_dim" -lt "$Y_THR" ]` or the bash syntax `if (( x_dim < X_THR && y_dim < Y_THR ))`

Comment: I'm tempted to argue that this is more a question about lightdm's config file format than a question about shells or programming, and thus that it would be better placed over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se] -- there's a reason we don't have a lightdm tag on our site (and while the answer involved a lot of C, I can't really justify calling it a C question).

Comment: Think about `x_dim=${resolution%x*}` and `y_dim=${resolution#*x}` as a more efficient way to split your resolution out into two separate variables, btw.

Comment: (You might also want to call `xrandr | grep -w connected` _only once_ and store and reuse the output instead of invoking it three separate times; if you want to lean into the bashisms you could use `readarray` or `mapfile` to consume its output into an array and then you can just check the array's length and never need to call `wc -l`; similarly, finding the primary display no longer requires awk at that point -- you have a short list of items you can iterate over and inspect).

Comment: An interesting problem, all great comments above, and looks like your problem is solved,  but you may have solved it yourself by reading the section "How to turn a bad script into a good questoin" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . This is a more directed version of [mcve] which is the same idea, but super generic to fit all programming paradigms AND is the core principle of posting a reasonable question on S.O. (all IMHO).  Good luck to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightDM **doesn't use a shell at all** when it invokes `display-setup-script`, but rather performs its own shell-like parsing. Therefore `|| true` is passed as two extra arguments (`'||'` and `'true'`, which you'll see if you do something like `echo "Called as: ${0@Q} ${*@Q}" >&2` in your script), not treated as syntax.

Processing this configuration starts in [`lightdm/src/seat.c`](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/1ade713d2da82abf5ece9a26dc79ffa908d77f89/src/seat.c#L1326):

```c
    if (script && !run_script (seat, display_server, script, NULL))
    {
        l_debug (seat, "Stopping display server due to failed setup script");
        display_server_stop (display_server);
        return;
    }
```

Following the definition of `run_script`, in [`lightdm/src/process.c`](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/1ade713d2da82abf5ece9a26dc79ffa908d77f89/src/process.c#L193), we see LightDM trying to parse the command line *itself* instead of passing it to a shell to parse:

```c
    if (!g_shell_parse_argv (priv->command, &argc, &argv, &error))
    {
        g_warning ("Error parsing command %s: %s", priv->command, error->message);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

...and then, below, directly executing the child:

```c
        execvp (argv[0], argv);
```

No shell is involved, so shell syntax is not honored.